# Requirejs to load templates without model definition

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I notice that every time you use require you need to first define all the modules. In my case, I don't really need to do that right now, I just need to load templates for backbone.

Is it possible to load a templates with out module definition?

Which may look something like this:

```
View = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'entry',
    initialize: function(model, response){
        console.log("View Intialized: "+this.model.get('id') )

        _.bindAll(this, "render") 
        this.model.bind('change', this.render)
        this.template = _.template( require( ['text!templates/users/view.html'] ) ) //would look something like this?
    },
    render: function(){
        var rendered = this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) 
        $(this.el).html( rendered ); 
        return this 
    }
})
```

I have multiple views in a file in most cases and not sure how the module define will work with that. Although, I would a similar simple solution like above.

EDIT: In addtion to the answer, a lighter solution is here http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/backbone-js-lessons-learned-and-improved-sample-app/ where you load all the templates initially which may be better than loading as needed.

Comment: Did you try your code? As long as your view shouldn't be accessed from another module, this should work (of course require.js should be loaded).

Comment: Maybe you need a basic require.config object to set the baseUrl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first off thank you for asking this question: I wrote a (bad) answer for it, then realized I didn't understand Require as well as I did, and it forced me to go educate myself some more :-)  Hopefully now I can provide a better answer.

There are two ways of using require:

1) Synchronous: `var baz = require('foo/bar')`

2) Asynchronous: `require(['foo/bar'], function(bar) {var baz = bar;}`

The problem is, you're combining the two with this line:

```
this.template = _.template( require( ['text!templates/users/view.html'] )
```

You're giving the dependencies to require as an array, as if you were doing the async-style, but you're expecting it to immediately return the module, sync-style.

The solution is simple, either:

A) Pre-load (either with a define call or an async require call) your templates, then use the sync-style syntax:

```
this.template = _.template( require('text!templates/users/view.html')
// NOTE: If you don't pre-load this won't work
```

or:

B) Use the async-style:

```
require(['text!templates/users/view.html'], function(viewTemplate) {
    View = Backbone.View.extend({
    // rest of your code
    this.template = _.template(viewTemplate);
})
```

Comment: As a side comment, if you ever want more powerful templates than Underscore's, check out the Handlebars library.  Not only is it a great templating library, but someone made a library for using it with require called HBS that lets you bring in templates already compiled.

Comment: I did just find out how much better handlebars is in comparison, I will be converting soon!